# How to attach files to list item using Client Object Model?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app, csom

I have a SharePoint List to which I am adding new `ListItems` using the Client Object Model.

Adding `ListItems` is not a problem and works great.

How to add Attachments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below logic

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("listtitle");
ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
var attachment = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
attachment.FileName = "fileName";
attachment.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("streamFile"));
Attachment att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachment);                                        
context.Load(att);                                     
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(webUri, userName, password))
{         
   var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
   var listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
   var attachment = listItem.SaveAttachment(filePath);
}
```

where

```
static class ListItemExtensions
{
    public static Attachment SaveAttachment(this ListItem item,string path)
    {
        var ctx = item.Context;
        var attachmentInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
        attachmentInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            attachmentInfo.ContentStream = fs;
            var attachment =  item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachmentInfo);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return attachment;
        }
    }

}


public static ClientContext GetContext(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
    return new ClientContext(webUri) { Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword) };
}
```